# React Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How do I trigger `useEffect()` on a button click, rather than on rendering the component?

When I use it inside a function like this, I get an error stating:

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

```
function App() {

  function buttonClicked() {  
    useEffect(() => {
      // Fetch from API
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <h1 className="App-title">App Title</h1>
      </header>
      <p className="App-intro">
        To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
      </p>
      <button onClick={buttonClicked}>Make API Call</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your goal is to trigger data fetching upon clicking on a button, there's no need for `useEffect`. `useEffect` is used to replace the lifecycle hooks - `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`.

Think about this - without hooks, will you need these lifecycle hooks at all to achieve what you want? With classes, you simply have to use `this.state` and a callback that triggers upon clicking of the button; you wouldn't use any of these lifecycle hooks.

The side effect you want to achieve is data fetching, but that's a user-triggered effect and `useEffect` is not helpful here. `useEffect` is only helpful when you want to have side effects during the lifecycle of the component.

The code below should do what you want to achieve with hooks, and you don't need `useEffect`, you only need `useState`.

```js
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  function fetchData() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        setUser(data.results[0]);
      });
  };
  
  return <div>
    <p>{user ? user.name.first : 'No data'}</p>
    <button onClick={fetchData}>Fetch Data</button>
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you misunderstood the usage of `useEffect`. It's like `componentDidUpdate` hook - it is being triggered depending on value change, not directly by some function. When `render` method is called, `useEffect` is also called. Hard to tell what is your goal, but from your snippet it makes most sense just to call `fetch` without any hook. But to answer your question, one way to trigger `useEffect` would be to update your state and you can create `useEffect` hook to be triggered only if value of particular property is changed:

```
const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch from API
}, [buttonClicked]); 

<button onClick={() => setButtonClicked(true)}>Make API Call</button>
```

Now when you click, `useEffect` should be triggered, but because you added `, [buttonClicked]`, it won't be called if any other property value changes.

Comment: From the docs: "The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components". My goal is to perform a side effect on button click, not on render. Your solution with the state assumes I only want to perform a side effect on the first button click, what if I want perform it on every click? Also creating state variable simply to trigger useEffect seems clunky?

Comment: So not uses this hook. If you invoke Http request from `buttonClicked`, it is considered as side-effect. If you for some reason still need to use `useEffect` hook, replace `setButtonClicked(true)` with `setButtonClicked(!buttonClicked)` - hook will be called every time button clicked

Comment: Ah ok, I was assuming useEffect was to wrap all side effects for functional components. I'll just avoid using and avoid setting state so, thanks.